# Why? Is this the norm for new people?

Tags: discussion

I am pretty new to all this forum stuff and was in hope I would find some answers to my questions. The 1st question I asked was closed after 2 responses, doesn't seem like that good of a forum to me.

Very disappointed.

Comment: It's not a forum, but a Q&A repo.  A closed question isn't a mark against your account or necessarily bad, it just means that answers can't be posted until the question is better suited to this Stack Exchange.  You can [edit] a question and it will be automatically queued for review to be reopened.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: And this question will probably be migrated to https://meta.blender.stackexchange.com :)

Comment: Hi bobkoonce, you shouldn't judge too quickly. i didn't see your question but in most cases beginners often describe their problems with just 1 or 2 sentences and think that is enough - which in 99% of all cases isn't enough. We need a lot of informations to help you because Blender is very complex and the problems are also often complex. And often there could be several reasons why your problem occured. So i propose editing/improving your question by adding screenshots of what you have and what you want. And i personally love questions with provided blend file so we don't have to guess.

Comment: But i can understand your frustration because this site seems to be very rude if you are emotional and you questions was quickly closed (believe me, i was often in that situation and i was disappointed too). But the more effort you invest to your question the more likely it will attract people who want to answer and it won't be closed. And after you got your first answer from the wonderful - sometimes genius - people here - you will love it. Yes, some people are annoying  - try to ignore them. Most of them are very helpful and have great knowledge like Robin Betts, Moonboots ....

Comment: try not to take it as an attack on yourself - is my advice ;)

Answer (score 3):

It is not the norm; but it does happen fairly regularly.

Stack Exchange itself is an attempt to do things differently than other Q&A forums and has very different rules.  They try to warn new users in advance with things like the [Tour](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour) but it's not mandatory.

They also try to make clear that closing a question is only meant to give an opportunity to fix the question.  In your first question, for example, the close message says "Add details and clarify the problem being solved. This will help others answer the question."

Unfortunately, they also encourage downvoting questions that aren't well written; while at the same time encouraging "be nice" to new users.

And, how close a given forum adheres to the Stack Exchange model is entirely up to the community that makes up the forum.

Blender's stack exchange has the additional problem that being a technical forum, people ask questions that seem perfectly clear to them, but that lack information that we need to help solve the problem.

So, sometimes, a new user, widely experienced in other Q&A forums, comes along, asks a question that seems clear to them, gets asked for detail, and has their question "closed".  Not knowing how Stack Exchange works, they find themselves bewildered, as you have.

If you have any suggestions, as a new user, about how to make it easier for new users to realize that Stack Exchange is different, I'm sure the Exchange would like to hear them.